# Морфемный разбор "разломлю"

Tags: морфемный-разбор

затрудняюсь.
Разломлю - л суффикс, ю окончание
Или л - соединительная согласная

Comment: В ответе ниже пишут, что корень ломл..Как узнать правильный вариант?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Соединительная согласная" ***Л*** называется интерфикс.  У Литневской на  **[стр.18](https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p18_TOC_idp946032)**  есть статья: **Соединительные элементы в слове (интерфиксы).**

Интерфиксы, используемые в словоизменении существительных, принято считать **наращениями** корня. Поэтому ***Л*** лучше присоединить к корню.

```
  Примеры разбора в Сети:  
  
  Разломлю́
  раз — приставка,
  лом — корень,
  л — соединительная согласная,
  ю — окончание,
  разломл - основа.

  Люблю
  люб — корень
  л — интерфикс
  ю — окончание
  любл  — основа слова
```

Comment: Спасибо. Получается ломл - корень. А в слове люблю корень любл, ю - окончание. Правильно?)

Comment: Да, все  верно..

Comment: Тому, кто минус поставил. Почему минусовка? Что-нибудь у Литневской не так?  Тогда оставьте комментарий. А вот ссылаться только на историческое чередование недостаточно. Это причина  для использования интерфикса, да и то неплохо бы добавить  пояснение (зачем нам интерфикс/наращение).  Необоснованные минусовки на форум вообще нежелательны, так как вносят неприязненные отношения между участниками и мешают работать.

Comment: Пришлось тоже поставить минус – для равновесия точек зрения. А дальше что?

Answer (score 1):

Сомневаюсь, что это соединительная гласная.

В русском языке есть исторические чередования:

1)в-вл;

2)м-мл;

3)п-пл;

4)б-бл.

Все это корневые чередования, поэтому "л" нужно отнести к **корню**:

1)**лом**ить - **ломл**ю;

2)пре**лом**ить - пре**ломл**ение.

Comment: Спасибо, значит раз - приставка, ломл - корень, ю - окончание, правильно?